# How to call function from one file class to another file with onClick?

Tags: java, android

This is probably a duplicate, but i can't find any thing on this so here goes.

I want to call a function in a class from file B.java into A.java with the onClick. Problem is, i get an error every time I add the line in. Here is my code and I'll give the error at the bottom.

A.java

```
import com.example.app.B;

public class MainService extends Service
{
    private CallFunc callFunc;
    private Button btn;

    public void onCreate()
    {
        callFunc = new CallFunc();
        btn = new Button(this);

        //Code for setOnClickListener
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            callFunc();
        }
    }
}
```

B.java

```
public class CallFunc
{
    public CallFunc()
    {
        //Stuff to do
    }
}
```

Error I get

```
The method callFunc() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}
```

Comment: create a instance of that class and call the method

Comment: `callFunc.yourMethod();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have in your `B.java` is a constructor not a method. A constructor is a special case method that gets invoked when an instance of that class is created. It is used to correctly initialise and populate new instances of a class.

What you were probably trying to do is:

```
public class CallFunc
{
    public CallFunc()
    {
        // this is the constructor
        // initialise the class instance here
    }

    public void someMethod()
    {
        // a method you can call
        // perform actions here
    }
}
```

Then in the `onCreate()` of your MainService you should:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    callFunc.someMethod();
}
```

**However**, you are extending Service and using UI components (Button and onClick) when a Service does not have a UI. Are you sure you didn't want to use an Activity?

Comment: I am sure i do not want to use an Activity. Reason is, I am using this to display over other applications using WindowManager. I have been successful thus far.

Comment: Ok, just checking in case. Your difficulty is a beginner one so I wanted to clear that up in case you chose it mistakenly.

Answer (score 1):

```
//you are not calling your function:
import com.example.app.B;

 public class MainService extends Service
{
private CallFunc callFunc;
private Button btn;

public void onCreate()
{
    callFunc = new CallFunc();
    btn = new Button(this);

    //Code for setOnClickListener
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        callFunc.callFunc();//It is a good idea to use better method names. it looks like you are calling your constructor, not a method.
    }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CallFunc class,

```
public CallFunc()
{
   //Stuff to do
}
```

means it's constructor. It get called when you create it. In here `callFunc = new CallFunc();`.
You can include it to onClick method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    callFunc = new CallFunc();
}
```

Better way is to do this is add a method to CallFunc class because method means you do something. You do your stuff in that method. Class means a object like a car. Car can be drive. so it should have dirve() method. Then car.drive() means you drive the car.  :)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    callFunc.someMethod();
}
```